# Best free blogging site that allows AdSense and other advertising?

Tags: advertising, blog, free, google-ads

I'm looking to start my own blog. Under the incredibly vain assumption that anyone cares what I think, I'd like to put up some ads to fund my, um, habits, yeah. I don't want to have to pay anything, nor do I want to host it myself (if possible).

What blogging platform fits this bill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for self hosting or hosting on someone else's server?

The reason that I ask is because if you host it yourself, then you can do pretty much anything you want. If you host on someone else's servers and its free, chances are that they'd want to make some sort of money from your blog so the money from the ads would more than likely go to them.

If you go down the self hosted route, [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) tends to be a firm favourite.

If you want someone else to host it you have quite a large choice from [Wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com), [Posterous](http://www.posterous.com), [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com), [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com). However, I'm 99% certain that none of these sites let you make money of adwords, since they are free to start with.

**Edit**

As stated below, blogger allows you to monetize your blog with adsense.

Comment: Well, as a web developer, I know I can do whatever I want if I host it myself. I'm a hair to busy for that though, so as my question stated, I don't want to host it myself.

Comment: The last four you mentioned, are you sure they allow me to collect revenue from AdWords and the like?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: You may want to revise your answer again. I've started using Blogger, and they do allow adsense and amazon associates and in fact have a tab called "Monetize" that allow you to easily set up these things.

Comment: Thinking about it, that would make sense since blogger is owned by Google and so they're going to make money from adsense as well as the blog owner.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Oh, and in case you give a crap, here's my blog: http://geekdadslife.blogspot.com

Comment: At the same time you'll lose all your blogs if they decide to close your account without warning.